# MSI Log Debug Log Sink

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installshield

I have an InstallShield MSI project.  When I pass an MSIHANDLE from an InstallScript custom action to a managed assembly initialized via DotNetCoCreateObject(), the value received within my managed code is -2.

Does anyone know if it is possible to access an MSIHANDLE from an InstallScript custom action that calls into managed code via DotNetCoCreateObject()?  I'd like to log my custom action results to the same log file as the rest of the installation.  I am using InstallShield 2010, Windows Install 4.5 and .Net 3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is only possible via a managed custom action and requires use of InstallShield's InstallShield.Interop.Msi.dll to get at the actual handle.

To write to the MSI log file from a managed custom action, this works:

```
 using (Msi.Install msi = Msi.CustomActionHandle(_msiHandle))
 {
     using (Msi.Record record = new Msi.Record(100))
     {
         record.SetString(0, "LOG: [1]");
         record.SetString(1, entry.Message);
         msi.ProcessMessage(Msi.InstallMessage.Info, record);
     }
 }
```

**NOTE:** As of IS2010, InstallShield.Interop.Msi.dll is not digitally signed, so the assembly with your managed custom action must also be unsigned.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that this only works if the CustomAction wasn't called from a DoAction on a control event. I have a custom action that uses this approach to write a message to the log. To test this, I attached the action to a button press in the UI and also as an action in the InstallExecuteSequence. The action attached to the UI didn't log the statement, whereas when the same action was ran as part of the ExecuteSequence it made it into the log.

Comment: Apparently, this is because MsiProcessMessage doesn't work from a DoAction control event. A way around this is to set a property with the message you want to log.

Comment: I am getting below error in MSI log after adding above code 
-----
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'InstallShield.Interop.Msi, Version=23.0.0.511, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
----
I added this dll to my project and i can see in output directory but How to load InstallShield.Interop.Msi dll into installer?

Comment: I resolved above mentioned error by adding the InstallShield.Interop.Msi dll to ISClrWrap table in Direct Editor under Additional Tools. This table has 3 columns. First Column -> Give the custom action name, second column "Dependecy0" third column "<ISProductFolder>\system\InstallShield.Interop.Msi.dll"

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. You'll have to manage your log output yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Another pt of clarification is that IS has two project types, InstallScript & MSI. You can only access the MSI handle within MSI projects.